# Rails, Devise: If user signed in create with user id, else without

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a streams controller and I am using Devise. Users can create streams either with (than the stream will have the id of the user in the db) or without account(than its a guest stream so to say). Currently I have the following create method:

```
def create
  @stream = current_user.streams.build(params[:name])
  if @stream.valid?
    @stream.save
    redirect_to c_path(@stream.name)
    flash[:notice] = "blabla"
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

But that doesnt work for guests, since I use the current_user. Now my plan was to create a if else (if signed in use the current_user, else not).

How would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, you can use `user_signed_in?` helper:

```
if user_signed_in?
  @stream = current_user.streams.build(params[:name])
else
  @stream = Stream.new(params[:name])
end
```

BTW make sure you pass valid params while building object.

Answer (score 0):

Devise has a user_signed_in? method. So you could do this:

```
if user_signed_in?
  @stream = current_user.streams.build(params[:name])
else
  @stream = Stream.new(params[:name])
end
```

Comment: You forgot `@stream =` in `else` clause.

Comment: So I did, thanks. That's what you get rushing at work :)